# Как добавить фигуре вместо заливки изображение?(JavaFX)

Tags: java, изображения, javafx, shape

Допустим есть Круг Circle circle
Нужно вместо заливки установить изображение Image img, подскажите как этого добиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть как минимум три способа. Два из них таковы:

- Если создается динамически фигура, то использовать метод `setFill()` и передать ему [ImagePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html). Это класс, с помощью которого можно залить фигуру картинкой по определенному паттерну.

  ```
  public class Main extends Application {
      private Rectangle rectangle;

      // тут прописывается правильный путь до картинки
      String imageBG = getClass().getResource("myBG.png").toExternalForm(); 

      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
          stage.setTitle("Image Pattern");
          Group root = new Group();
          Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 450);

          // создаем фигуру, в данном случае прямоугольник
          Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 100);        
          // Заливаем паттерном. Пока тупо картинкой
          rect.setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image(imageBG)));

          // Добавляем фигуру
          root.getChildren().add(rect);
          stage.setScene(scene);
          stage.show();
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }
  }
  ```

  Более подробно можно посмотреть [ТУТ](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html). Там есть даже примеры для наглядности.
- Допустим на сцене уже есть фигура, она нарисована и описана в файле `fxml`

  ```
   <Rectangle id="myImg" fx:id="myImage" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#e1011b" height="97.0" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="121.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
  ```

  то тогда можно ей присвоить айдишник (в данном случае `myImage`). А в нужном контроллере имеем поле, ссылающееся на объект с данным id, специально помеченное аннотацией `@FXML` говоря, что мы берем это из FXML.

  ```
  @FXML
  private Rectangle myImage;
  ```

  А далее также применяем паттерн. Т.е. как-то так выглядит контроллер:

  ```
  import javafx.fxml.FXML;
  import javafx.scene.image.Image;
  import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

  public class Controller {

      @FXML
      private Rectangle myImage;

      // тут нужен правильный путь до картинки
      Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("myBG.png").toExternalForm()); 

      public void initialize() {
          myImage.setFill(new ImagePattern(img));
      }
  }
  ```
- Третий вариант использовать `css` стили и конкретно метод `setStyle` ( это лучше попользоваться немного поиском [image: :-)] )

Comment: Спасибо, действует, а что делает метод toExternalForm() ? Вернее в каких случаях его необходимо использовать а в каких он не подходит?

Comment: @arachnoden там разными механизмами Url приводится к строке (ведь `getResource` возвращает `URL`). Но в принципе должно и `toString()` сработать